# How can I a add arabic character in my topic url in blogger?

Tags: url, blogger

I tried to use a Custom permanent link to my blog. But I can't use arabic character. I tried also to use utf-8 code but the "%" is invalid in blogger. What can I do please?

```
www.online.com/يكتمل
www.online.com/%D9%8A%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%85%%D9%84
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to achieve what you want to do. According to the [blog post](https://blogger.googleblog.com/2012/07/customize-your-posts-with-permalinks.html) on the official blog -

> At present, the characters allowed in a custom URL are limited to:
>   a-z, A-Z, 0-1. The only special characters available are underscore,
>   dash, and period.

The Labels field has no such limitations and allows for using encoded characters (for example - https://tests-blogger.blogspot.com/search/label/%D9%8A%D9%83%D8%AA%D9%85%D9%84)